# Database file at path [./database/database.sqlite] does not exist. Ensure this is an absolute path to the database. (laravel10)

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-filament

I have created a database schema and now I need to transform it into code for a project in laravel. I installed filament panel and created a filament user for the admin login :

```
php artisan make:filament-user
```

now when I try to log in as admin in the login form I receive the above-mentioned error!

I'm using the project as a clone from gitlab and I use Ubuntu on Windows.

My .env file :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:wBRsBCpS5bzoOA06ye1EIlPeQ8au9is1j3+XNNSj/j4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=./database/database.sqlite
DB_FOREIGN_KEYS=true
```

My .env.example file :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=slite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

My .env.save file :

```
PP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:rxPvNOP34FnNUSw1s9k2+uXvGvQ8Q5Z5YZiTrnfUFwY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and my database.php file :

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),

'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],
```

Comment: Did you take the error message's advice and use an absolute path?

Comment: I've tried different ways from stackoverflow previously suggestions and none works!

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=
```

or

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=/home/dev/projects/projectA/database/database.sqlite
```

Comment: in .env file, in .env.example or in .env.save file?

Comment: also I want to configurate with mysql database!

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the absolute path to the sqlite database.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#sqlite-configuration

Comment: I want to use MySQL!

Comment: That is not what the question says, for that take a look at the doumentation on how to setup MySQL databases.

Comment: I've done the database schema in mysql workbench. I read that laravel supports 5 databases (mariadb, mysql, postgresql, sqlite, sql server). I installed filament panel and wanted to create a user for admin panel but without databse I can't log in !

Comment: You need to create MySql database and set name and credentials in .env. I don't know what your environment is, i.e.: you can install XAMPP for database creation.

Comment: I'm using windows subsystem for linux on windows because I had an error earlier to start the project in windows!

Comment: Already solved the issue with xampp! if someone goes through the same issues, comment here !